# .htaccess wildcard redirect excluding certain subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We have a wildcard subdomain for our application which we want to redirect to the root domain in all instances except for some subdomains which we allow and the application handles differently.

For example:

- `subdomain.example.com`
- `anything.example.com`

Should all redirect to `example.com`.

However, we have other subdomains which we want to allow to remain the same.

For example:

- `api.example.com`
- `staging.example.com`

Here is the `.htaccess` file we have at the moment:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried using a negative regular expression but had no luck:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(api\.|staging\.)(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:api|staging)\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.([^.]+\..+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```